# Does filtering by partition key with the IN() operator result in a full table scan?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    group_id text,
    user_id uuid,
    creation_date timestamp,
    details text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((group_id, user_id))
)
```

Both the group_id and user_id together form the partition key. So can I query like the following?

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE group_id="A"
AND user_id IN(80115b8d-d0d3-43f9-ae2d-6d873e3c4348, 03164602-9a31-4a05-a3af-56ec0ea74ef6);
```

Will this result in a full scan causing performance issues?

Answer (score 2):

> Will this result in a full scan causing performance issues?

So let's try this out.  If I break-up the SELECT statement above into two queries and run them with `TRACING ON`, I get the following results (3 node cluster in GCP w/ RF=3):

```
SELECT * FROM  user WHERE group_id='A' AND user_id=80115b8d-d0d3-43f9-ae2d-6d873e3c4348;
```

2792 microseconds

```
SELECT * FROM  user WHERE group_id='A' AND user_id=03164602-9a31-4a05-a3af-56ec0ea74ef6;
```

3267 microseconds

```
SELECT * FROM  user WHERE group_id='A' AND user_id in(80115b8d-d0d3-43f9-ae2d-6d873e3c4348, 03164602-9a31-4a05-a3af-56ec0ea74ef6);
```

27047 microseconds

In looking through the trace report from the `IN` query, it's definitely talking to each node in the cluster.  But I think the raw difference in response times indicates that running a separate query for each key combination out-performs the `IN` query.  By a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Queries which filter multiple partitions using the `IN()` operator will always perform worse because the coordinator has to parse the request to fire off individual requests for each item in the list.

Two (maybe three) partitions in the `IN()` list is possibly fine for the application to tolerate but anything more than that puts significant strain on the request coordinator.

The `IN()` operator was not designed for filtering partitions. The only recommended usage is for filtering rows withIN a single partition.

Multi-partition reads is a scatter-gather access pattern which either (a) indicates an incorrect data model, or (b) an analytics workload (not OLTP). If your application use case does require multi-partition reads, our recommendation is to perform multiple asynchronous requests which will maximise the throughput of your cluster. Cheers!